# Python : Passing function as parameter and multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, function-parameter

I'm new with python and I can't find why the "Without_thread" class works and not the "With_thread" class.

The purpose of my "With_thread" class is to launch a new thread when I call it with a function so I can execute any function at the same time. (<==This is what I would like to do)

```
import threading

class With_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, target, *args):
        self._target = target
        self._args = args
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self._target(*self._args)
```

The "Without_thread" is almost the same class, the only thing changing here is that I don't use threads.

```
class Without_thread():
    def __init__(self, target, *args):
        self._target = target
        self._args = args

    def foo(self):
        self._target(*self._args)
```

I test my code with this:

```
def some_Func(data, key):
    print("some_Func was called : data=%s; key=%s" % (str(data), str(key)))

f1 = With_thread(some_Func, [1,2], 6)
f1.start()
f1.join() 

f2 = Without_thread(some_Func, [1,2], 6)
f2.foo()
```

The output from f1 is:

```
    self._target(*self._args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

The output from f2 is:

```
some_Func was called : data=[1, 2]; key=6
```

I would really appreciate if you can help me with this, and thank you very much for your time!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *suspect* the issue is caused by some sort of conflict between your _target and _args and the same attributes defined within Thread.

You don't need to define `__init__()` or `run()` in With_thread. The Thread classes own **init** allows you to pass keyword arguments `target` and `args`, and its `run()` method will run target with args and kwargs provided at intiialisation.

So, you can get rid of With_thread entirely, and then call:

```
f1 = threading.Thread(target=some_Func, args=([1,2], 6))
```

Comment: I tried changing the name of the args passed to the thread and the exception jumps.  To narrowing the issue, if I print the type of `_target` is `'NoneType'` and it should be `<class 'function'>`

Comment: Ok, we can come back to that. Does my suggestion work? If so, why do you want to subclass Thread?

Comment: your solutions works fine.  I'm only asking for the reason  of why don't works as Rotsap wrote it.

Comment: Good question, it works fine for me on python 2.7/x64

Comment: in some_Func what values should be their